# How to integrate log4j 2 into my Spring project?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, logging

So I just downloaded Spring Tool Suite, created a new Maven project, and am confused as to how to get Log4j integrated into my project.

Here is my project structure and the class I'm trying to create a logger in.  Please note that none of these imports listed under LoggerFactory work - every time I select one it says `LoggerFactory.getLogger cannot be resolved to a type`.

[image]

And here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Use Logger.getLogger(this.class); to get a logger instance , I don't think u need loggerfactory

Comment: Okay, I tried that and now get this: `Logger.getLogger can not be resolved to a type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build and Install you project after you have made an entry for Log4j in your pom.xml

Remove these entries for log4j from your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And only a single entry is sufficient for log4j in your pom

Also always reference Log4j as below in your class

```
private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger
.getLogger(classname.class.getName());
```

Comment: This works!  It looks like the only thing I was doing wrong was I had `private static final Logger logger = new Logger.getLogger(MockMailSender.class);` rather than `private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger
.getLogger(MockMailSender.class.getName());`.  Can you explain why the way I did it was wrong?

Comment: My apologies, just accepted it.  Can you explain to me why your way is correct?  I'm new to both Spring and Maven and I feel like more explanation would be useful to me

Comment: As you see in your code you did a new Logger.getLogger() instance on the Logger Factory.This is actually not required as you directly use that in a static way like Logger.getLogger() which is the right way to use the Log4j in your code. you can check the log4j api for more details as to what you should do correctly. It has nothing to do with Spring and Maven. you just need to use it in correct way and make the correct entry.